# Что означает эта строка

Tags: javascript

Добрый день, недавно начал изучать javascript, в одной из тем наткнулся на такой код:

```js
function hardWork() {
 
  for (i = 0; i < 1e8; i++) hardWork[i % 2] = i;
}
```

В принципе понимаю, что делает эта функция, но никогда не видел такого выражения `hardWork[i % 2] = i;`, буду благодарен, если кто-то объяснит, для чего нужны тут квадратные скобки

Comment: А зачем такая ф-ция? Судя по всему у неё одна цель - повесить ПК.

Comment: @nick_n_a, ну правильно, название функции как бы намекает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Квадратные скобки применяются для получения/добавления параметра в объект.

Обычно скобочки используются если имя параметра заранее неизвестно, либо параметр не является валидным js идентификатором (к примеру содержит пробелы или спец символы).

Прим:

```
var foo = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
//получить 'a'
var a = foo['a'] // аналочино a = foo.a
//добавить новое поле 'c' равное 3
foo['c'] = 3 // аналогично foo.c = 3

//добавить новое поле (название которого хранится в переменной)
var param_name = 'my cool param'
foo[ param_name ] = 'some value' // аналога с использованием точки нет.
```

В js функции являются объектами типа `Function`. Поэтому в них (как и во все остальные объекты) можно добавлять новые свойства или изменять значения существующих (хотя не всех,  например [`name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name) и [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length) нельзя изменить).

Это может использоваться к примеру для кэширования результата работы функции:

```
function fib( n ){
     //функция считающая н-ое число Фибоначчи 
     //  (0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, ... (n-2)+(n-1) )
     console.log( 'calc fib of', n ) 
     if( n == 1 ) return 1;
     if( n == 0 ) return 0
     if( !( n in fib ) ) 
        fib[ n ] = fib( n - 1 ) + fib( n - 2 );
     return fib[ n ]
}

fib( 3 ) /* напечатает
     calc fib of 3
     calc fib of 2
     calc fib of 1
     calc fib of 0
     calc fib of 1 
        т.е. функция выполнилась 5 раз
*/
// повторный вызов
fib( 3 ) /* напечатает
     calc fib of 3
        функция выполилась только 1 раз (не пришлось расчитывать всё заново)
*/
```